# Is there any way to get GIMP make the "Keep Aspect Ratio" option a default option for scaling?

Tags: gimp

Only asking this question because no one else appears to have done so. In GIMP, when using Transform > Scale, the option to keep the aspect ratio (hidden away in the primary toolbox rather than the Scaling window) is not a default. Is there any way to make "Keep Aspect Ratio" a default? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Select the Scale Tool in the tool box. In the Tool Options, select the *Keep Aspect Ratio* option.

Click *Edit > Preferences > Tool Options > Save Tool Options Now*

You can also have GIMP remember the Tool Options settings in the current state just before exiting the program, by checking the *Save tool options on exit* option. If you don't want this to happen make sure you uncheck that option! Unchecking it will ensure the tool options you saved will never change.

Alternatively, leave the Keep Aspect Ratio option unchecked, and instead hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag one of the corner handles, and the aspect ratio will be constrained.  This is how I usually use the tool.

For more information, check [the documentation on the Scale Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html).